# getting network on exception thread when I run httpResponse

Tags: android, eclipse, json

I am just writing a simple program that can query a mysql database using JSON and PHP but I am still getting a Network on main thread exception even though I am using Async.

```
public class FetchActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button btnMushroom;
Button btnFlower;
Button btnStar;

String decription;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// JSON parser class
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
private static final String TAG_PRODUCT = "product";
private static final String TAG_DECRIPTION = "decription";

 private static final String url_get_image = "http://14.201.33.133/fetchfarmp       /getUrl.php";

static String imageUrl = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fetch);

    btnMushroom = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mushroom);
    btnMushroom.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            decription = "Mario Mushroom";

            new GetUrl().execute();



            new DownloadImageTask((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_mario))
            .execute(imageUrl);
}

    });

    }






@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fetch, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



 /**
 * Background Async Task to Get complete product details
 * */
class GetUrl extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(FetchActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading product details. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }


    /**
     * Getting product details in background thread
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        // updating UI from Background Thread
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // Check for success tag
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("decription", decription));

                    System.out.println("Attempting to run php ....");  

                    // getting product details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that product details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                            url_get_image, "GET", params);
                    System.out.println("json object Created!!!");  

                    // check your log for json response
                    Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {

                        System.out.println("Success I'm in!");                       
                        // successfully received product details
                        JSONArray productObj = json
                                .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);
                        String imageUrl = product.getString("link");



                    }else{
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        return null;
    }


}

}
```

I got a class got JSONParser which handles the query and is suppose to return a JSONObject back from the PHP code. I have checked the PHP code and it returns a JSONObject successfully. 
The exception occurs once I run HTTPResponse in the JSONParser class. What am I doing wrong?

LOGCAT:

```
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at     android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1144)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at com.example.fetchfarmtake9000.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:67)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at com.example.fetchfarmtake9000.FetchActivity$GetUrl$1.run(FetchActivity.java:140)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
10-15 19:49:08.427: E/AndroidRuntime(21245):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 19:50:32.939: I/Process(21245): Sending signal. PID: 21245 SIG: 9
```

Comment: done, far is there a easier way to indent all code by four spaces? draining to just go from line to line xD

Comment: for indenting though, use notpad+, select all text and press TAB. Done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you have inside doInBackground() this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
...
}
```

?
This is place where working code should be without any sending to different threads.

It breaks all you are trying to accomplish. Please see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html to know how to implement background tasks.

```
/**
  * Getting product details in background thread
  * */
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            // Check for success tag
            int success;
            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("decription", decription));

                System.out.println("Attempting to run php ....");  

                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                // Note that product details url will use GET request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                        url_get_image, "GET", params);
                System.out.println("json object Created!!!");  

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Single Product Details", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {

                    System.out.println("Success I'm in!");                       
                    // successfully received product details
                    JSONArray productObj = json
                            .getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCT); // JSON Array

                    // get first product object from JSON Array
                    JSONObject product = productObj.getJSONObject(0);
                    return product.getString("link"); // imageUrl



                }else{
                    // product with pid not found
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });

    return null;
}

protected void onPostExecute(String imageLink) {
     // do here whatever you need on UiThread with link.
     // but I suppose you should also download that image if not already fetched and return it as bitmap or something like it. 
 }
```

Comment: Sweet that worked like a charm, thanks very much Pihhan

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are actually doing a network operation on the main thread which is not allowed. Remove `runOnUiThread` from `doInBackground` and use `onPostExecute` and/or `onProgressUpdate` instead, to update your UI. You can pass values to `onProgressUpdate` from `doInBackground` by calling `publishProgress()`. See [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) documentation for more info.